# How to generate a line plot for data in column on condition of data in 2 other columns

Tags: python, plot

In my df I have 4 columns. The 1st two describe test conditions. Columns 3 & 4 are test data. Column 3 data is my fixed x axis data. I want a line overlay plot with legend for my Column 4 INL data, y axis data, for conditions based in Column 1 & 2.
The below code shows an example df. I can Group test_no and temperature columns to get min/max data from the INL data for the values of the group data that I want. I can't use the same group set-up to plot INL data for test_no=0,1 & Temperature=25,50. How can I achieve this? Thanks

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'Test_no': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 'Temperature': [25, 25, 25, 25, 50, 50, 50, 50, 25, 25, 25, 25, 50, 50, 50, 50], 'Codes': [0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,], 'INL':[0,1.1,-0.9,0, 0,1.0,-0.8,0, 0,0.9,-0.7,0, 0,1.2,-0.6,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

groups = df.groupby(['Test_no','Temperature'])

#group data and get min,max,mean per Col1/2 group

result = groups.agg({'INL': ['min', 'max', 'mean']})
print(result)

#Plot data per Col1/2 group (start with C1:0,C2:25)

d = df.loc[df["Temperature"] == 25]

d = df.loc[df["Test_no"] == 0]

d['INL'].plot()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am relatively new to python but I was able to resolve my issue using the groupby() function to split the data into the groups that I required and then use matplotlib.pyplot to index and plot each group of data.
I'm sure there are more efficient solutions but this works!
Using the same DF as I used in the question I added the below code:

```
Tests = [g for _, g in df.groupby(['Test_no','Temperature'])]

plt.plot(Tests[0].Codes, Tests[0].INL, label='T0 25C') 
plt.plot(Tests[1].Codes, Tests[1].INL, label='T0 50C') 
plt.plot(Tests[2].Codes, Tests[2].INL, label='T1 25C') 
plt.plot(Tests[3].Codes, Tests[3].INL, label='T1 50C')

plt.xlabel("Codes") 
plt.ylabel("INL") 
plt.title("INL Data")
plt.legend() 
plt.show()
```

Or you can use a more compact code to plot:

```py
for (n, temp), Test in df.groupby(['Test_no','Temperature']):
    plt.plot(Test.Codes, Test.INL, label=f"T{n} {temp}C")
```